# Azure job is aborting after some

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, azure-webjobs, abort

I have two triggered webjobs created in ASP.Net core, CORN time set in appsettings.json . we have paid suscription.

1. Run every 5mins - `"CRONTIME": "0 */5 * * * *",`
2. Run every day - `"CRONTIME": "0 30 0 * * *",`

I publish the files using visual studio and trigger it manually from Azure and will run continuously. I set the idle time in configuration of appservice "WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT" & "SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT" to 90000 (24hrs++) and also in settings.job as more than 24hrs

```
"stopping_wait_time": 90000
```

The issue is both job aborted after some hours and log also couldn't find any errors

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you please share your `appsettings.json` file and the source code.